# Evergreen ornamental shrub identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

These images were taken in the middle of April in central Poland.

Plants are between 0.5 and a meter tall, and around a meter in diameter.

[image: shrub image 1]

[image: shrub image 1e]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I've edited your text to make it clearer (e.g. I assumed that state was meant to be date) — please check to make sure I haven't changed your intended meaning. I'm very short on time right now, but this looks like a laurel of some sort (genus: *Prunus*), which are common garden shrubs.